# Div in the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can i put a div in the bottom of the screen not the page ?

But i don't want to use `position:fixed` because i want once i scroll down , the div go up like other elements.

like the div in this [web site](http://www.centraledesmarches.com/)

Comment: Please clarify, it seems you're asking for mutually exclusive behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`vh` unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) to do this.

```css
body, html {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tan;
  top: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: it didn't work for the moment because the parent of my div is not `body` so the the top is calculated from the parent div

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this css to your  id or class:

```
div {   
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0; 
}
```

Comment: no i don't want to use `position: absolute;` because in my case  it let a empty space

Comment: Worth noting that it may not work if the element has a positioned ancestor.